# Large object streaming from PostgreSQL in JRuby?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jruby

How do I stream large objects from PostgreSQL in JRuby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JRuby you can't use the `pg` gem as you would in regular Ruby, so you can't use it's large object support.

However you do have access to `PgJDBC`, so you can use the large object features offered by PgJDBC, same as you would from Java directly. See:

- http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/largeobjects.html
- http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/binary-data.html#binary-data-example

This should work much the same in JRuby as in regular Java.